# Chamar a função JavaScript com apenas um clique

Tags: javascript

Gostaria de saber como faço para chamar mais de uma função com apenas um "Click".

```js
window.onload = function(){
    var btn = document.getElementById("resposta");
    btn.addEventListener("click",function(){

        var nomedoCliente = parseFloat(document.getElementById("nmCliente").value)
        calcular(nomedoCliente);
    },false);
    function calcular(a){

        var xNmCliente = document.getElementById("nmCliente").value
        var xVidas = document.getElementById("vidas").value
        var xMarca = document.getElementById("marca").value
        var a = 0
        var execucao
        var coringa = 0


        if (xVidas == "vidas1" && xMarca == "marca1" ) {
            a=1
        }
        else if (xVidas == "vidas1" && xMarca == "marca2" ) {
            a=1
        }
        else if (xVidas == "vidas2" && xMarca == "marca1" ) {
            a=4
        }
        else if (xVidas == "vidas3" && xMarca == "marca1") {
            a=3
        }
        else {
            coringa=0

        }


        if(xMarca=="marca1" && a =="3"){
            execucao = 34
        }
        else if (xMarca =="marca2" && a=="1"){
            execucao = 88
        }
        else{
            execucao == 0
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Quantas vidas temos?</p>
<select id = "vidas">
 <option value="vidas1" >Menos 1000</option>
 <option value="vidas2" >1000 a 5000</option>
 <option value="vidas3" >Mais de 5000</option>
</select>

<p >O quanto nossa marca é importante para a Operadora?</p>
<select id = "marca">
 <option value="marca1" >Pouco Importante</option>
 <option value="marca2" >Importante</option>
 <option value="marca3" >De relevância estratégica</option>
</select></br>
```

Gostaria de pegar o resultado de `a`, como acontece nesse outro `if`, para obter o resultado de `Execucao`.

É possível fazer tudo em apenas uma função?

Dessa forma que coloquei não acontece nada quando aperto `Resultado`. Já olhei outros tópicos, mas não está fazendo muito sentindo.

Comment: Se o código que esta aqui é o mesmo que você tem, então esta faltando o elemento **resposta**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Voce pode adicionar varios event listetiner a um botao (ou qualquer elemento) com funcoes diferentes.

```
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){ 
//seu primeiro codigo aqui
})

btn.addEventListener("click",function(){ 
//seu segundo codigo aqui
})
```

Se voce precisa que duas funcoes se comunique, basta criar duas funcoes diferentes.

```
        btn.addEventListener("click",function(){ 
        var recebeValorFuncao1 = funcao1();
        //passo o valor recebido da funcao1 para a funcao2
        funcao2(recebeValorFuncao1);    
        });

function funcao1(){
//faz qualquer coisa aqui
return 1;
}

function funcao2(recebeQualquerCoisa){
//usa o valor da funcao1 com a variavel "recebeQualquerCoisa"

return recebeQualquerCoisa + 1;

}
```

Comment: Ótimo, mas como faço para receber a resposta da primeira função por exemplo e usar na segunda ?

Answer (score 2):

> Gostaria de saber como faço para chamar mais de uma função com apenas um "Click".

Simples, chame a função quantas vezes quiser. Na teoria, ficaria assim:

```
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){

    var nomedoCliente = parseFloat(document.getElementById("nmCliente").value)
    calcular(nomedoCliente); // Chamou a função uma vez
    calcular(nomedoCliente); // Chamou a função outra vez!
    calcular(nomedoCliente); // E por aí vai... Pode chamar a função que quiser (e estiver carregada)
}, false);
```

Na prática, vc vai ter que adaptar conforme sua necessidade.

Mas não para por aí! Sua função está sobrescrevendo o parâmetro:

```
// ...
function calcular(a){       // a foi passado como parâmetro

    var xNmCliente = document.getElementById("nmCliente").value
    var xVidas = document.getElementById("vidas").value
    var xMarca = document.getElementById("marca").value
    var a = 0               // a foi sobrescrito com o valor: 0
    // ...
```

Sem mencionar os outros erros...

> Ótimo, mas como faço para receber a resposta da primeira função por exemplo e usar na segunda ?

Basta armazenar a resposta da função em uma variável e passar essa variável como argumento na outra função:

```
resposta = calcular(nomedoCliente);
novaResposta = umaFuncaoQualquer(resposta);
```